# Is there a way to build installers for a java application for multiple targets on the same platform?

Tags: java, installation, javapackager

I would like to build a .msi, .deb, and .pkg from the same source tree and on the same machine.

Distributable runtimes for Java9+ are no longer downloadable, so perfectly sane solutions like launch4j+nsis no longer work.

javapackager has been abandoned by Oracle.

OpenJDK's jpackager can't (and will never) cross compile for different build projects, and it isn't even a real product yet.

Is there a way to build installers for win/linux/macos from the same machine?

Is the promise of "compile once, run everywhere" is truly dead and buried?

I have a legacy java application that is now in limbo, since MacOS java8 doesn't support java.awt.desktop, which requires java9+

Answer (score 4):

I use since Java 9 and the inception of `jlink` and `jpackage` a cross platform setup made of different docker images and Virtual Machines, where I can build the runtimes and the installers (MSI, DEB/RPM and DMG/PKG) on the target platforms within' my host system.

For Mac, you can use a KVM image, if you don't have Apple Hardware, where you can issue commands over ssh.

For Windows, a Linux docker container is used, packed with wine, the OpenJDK for Windows, the Visual Studio build tools, WIX and CMake to perform the build of the runtime image and a customised MSI installer (since the `javapackage` version is too simple)

Comment: Docker isn't really crosscompiling, and it is insane to have to rely on a different vm for every target host, even in CI/CD. For example, c, c++, golang, rust don't need it. nsis doesn't need it. launch4j doesn't need it. They all support fully native crosscompiling (and even canadian cross). Java was sold as being CPU/platform independent, and requiring docker to do cross compiling completely undermines that concept.

Comment: @nyet sure, but this is a Java fault. To overcome to this limitation, Docker might help. And it depends on your requirements: to generate a MSI installer, you need a Windows platform

Comment: This was never the case before. NSIS + launch4j could make a windows installer anywhere.

Comment: Do you have a dockerfile example for your linux docker + wine + openjdk, pretty please?

Comment: @EricDuminil it's a little bit outdated now (for JDK15), but here you go: https://gist.github.com/madduci/05a434a66119e643ba79fe9d25c2b7f7
you should have a public accessible link to the archive file for the JDK, I host copy of releases on a private Nexus instance

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is not short. But I'll try to be brief and point to all relevant information.

The short answer is: you can do this.

The longer answer is: you still have to build a runtime for each target environment from within that target environment, but you only have to do this once. You can then save that runtime and reuse it to automatically build installers with your latest Java jars/code in a single environment. For example, use `jlink` to build the runtime image and `jpackage` to build the app image for Windows, Linux, and macOS (on those respective systems) then copy those app images to macOS and build an `nsis` installer (or installer builder of your choice) for each platform from within macOS.

When you update your code and recompile, you can just copy the new jars into the pre-built app image. You'll have to copy in all your dependencies, too, but that would be necessary for any installer. There is a config file in the runtime built by `jpackage` that has options, classpath, etc., which you can change without a need to rebuild the runtime.

1. Create a runable program, something as simple as

```
    package com.example;

    public class Greeter {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hi, I'm the greeter. Welcome.");
        }
    }
```

2. compile the program and place in a jar (call it `greeter.jar` for this example and place in the build directory, called `target` for this example)
3. run `jilnk` to build a runtime. The following command uses `jlink` from JDK11 and puts the result in a directory called `runtime`. This example includes all modules on the module path, but you can use `jdeps` to get just the modules you need. I suggest including all modules if you do not want to ever have to rebuid this runtime when your project evolves and depends on more of the Java runtime. Not to mention transitive dependencies on the JRE.

```
    > set JLINK=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6\bin\jlink.exe
    > "%JLINK%" --no-header-files --no-man-pages --compress=2 --strip-debug --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH --output runtime
```

4. run `jpackage` to build an app image suitable for packaging in an installer. This uses jpackage from JDK14 early access (the only version of the JDK that has `jpackage` at the time of this writing). The command line option `—win-console` is only for Windows and is only necessary if the program does something with stdin/stdout (the console). Our example writes to the console, so we need this. This argument will likely sometimes open a console window when running your application, so remove it if you have a pure windows based (gui) application.

```
    > set JPKG=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14-ea\bin\jpackage.exe
    > "%JPKG%" --type app-image -i target —win-console -n Greeter --main-class com.example.Greeter --main-jar greeter.jar --runtime-image runtime
```

5. run the application with `.\Greeter\Greeter.exe`

The resulting app image (in the `app-image` directory) can be used to build an installer with your favorite install builder (I use NSIS). You can do this on any platform. Furthermore, when you update you program you only have to copy your new jars into the app image. There is no need to rebuild the app image or the runtime. This copy of the jars can take place on any platform, and there is no need for Windows to be run in order to build a new installer for a new version of your application.

If your application has jar dependencies (say from Maven central), you’ll need to copy those jars to the `Greeter/app` directory and update `app.classpath` in the `Greeter/app/Greeter.cfg` file. Again, all this can be done on any platform, no need to start up the target platform (Windows in my case).

Also, `jpackage` is an officially supported tool but only available in EA JDK 14 (it's Feb 2020 as I write). JDK 14 may be downloaded and `jpackage` can be used with other versions of JDK (like JDK 11 LTS).

See https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/a-brief-example-using-the-early-access-jpackage-utility

The JEP for `jpackage` has been marked "Closed/Delivered" suggesting the tool is mature and just waiting for JDK 14 to be released: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/343

There is an example project on GitHub that has a lot of useful command line examples on how to run `jlink` and `jpackage`: https://github.com/jtconnors/SocketClientFX
Though this project uses outdated command options. You can run `jpackage --help` to get the new options.

**Useful Links:**

JDK 14 (early access until March 17th, 2020): http://jdk.java.net/14/

Explains non-modular usage of jlink: https://medium.com/azulsystems/using-jlink-to-build-java-runtimes-for-non-modular-applications-9568c5e70ef4

jlink manual: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm#JSWOR-GUID-CECAC52B-CFEE-46CB-8166-F17A8E9280E9

jpackage - run with the `-help` option to get good reference information

Comment: Whilst I was able to build an installation package on linux for windows I met an update problem. I created an app-image on windows usng jlink/jpackage and used this on linux to build a NSIS windows install package, that installed OK on windows.

Comment: However when I updated my modular java app on linux and copied over the jars into the windows app-image, the resulting NSIS package didn't contain my java app updates. I found that the app-image contained this file: /lib/runtime/lib/modules -in my case about 30Mb. This file seems to be an amalgamation my app jars compiled on Windows. If I update my java app on linux and copy over the 'modules' file into the windows app-image then when I install on windows the app fails because the 'modules' file was build for linux. The only way to update the 'modules' file is on windows - defeats whole object

Comment: @DavidMiller, I am using the method I described above, so I can assure you that it works. There seem to be some differences - that perhaps I didn't think to include - between what you are doing and what I did. Let me see if I can clarify them in my answer.

Comment: Ok, I think I see where the problem is. You really need to create the Greeter app in my instructions. Then overwrite that app _after_ creating the app-image and copying the app-image to Linux. Do _not_ create an app-image with your app. I know this may sound counter intuitive, but the problem you encountered is precisely a result of not breaking down the steps into small pieces as I did in the instructions in the answer. I suggest using the Greeter app as a test case and go through all the steps. Then update the Greeter app to have a different message and see it work.

Comment: That's great, thank you. It's gives me confidence that it works. Yes I get what you mean - create the app-image one-time on Windows without my app, and then copy this image to Linux and then overwrite with my app. I'll look more carefully at you Greeter app steps again. BTW great answer to the original question. Hope your clarification  to my difficulties helps others.

Comment: I have almost all of this working, with a few minor oddities, one of which is that running jpackage to make an installer actually runs the installer when it is done.. is that expected? Can it be disabled?

Comment: In any case, that last part is irrelevant because I want not only the .app creation (which requires a bunch of templating for both the Info.plist and <app>.cfg files)  but also .pkg/.dmg creation to not require a Mac.

Comment: I think you can handle the plist and cfg files just fine. I see there are tools for building dmg files on Linux https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117461/how-do-i-create-a-dmg-file-on-linux-ubuntu-for-macos

Comment: I feel your pain because I struggled with these same issues. I'm building on macOS for Windows. Let me know if you get this working.

Answer (score 3):

**Creating a Windows MyApp.exe and MyApp-setup.exe on linux:**

I don't need `jpackage` at all, only `jlink`, `launch4j`, and `nsis`:

- Use `jlink` once natively to create the runtime and tar off the
  results for use on other machines.
- `launch4j` can be instructed to use that runtime, and `nsis` can be
  told to copy the whole runtime on install.

**Creating a MacOS `MyApp.app` on linux:**

- Use `jlink` to create a tarfile that can be reused to recreate
  `Contents/runtime/Contents/Home` (like for windows above)
- Copy in the `jpackage` generated
  `Contents/runtime/Contents/Info.plist` and
  `Contents/runtime/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib`
- Copy in the `jpackage` generated `Contents/MacOS/MyApp` stub and
  `Contents/MacOS/libapplauncher.dyn`and hope they never have to
  change.
- Create `Contents/Info.plist` and `Contents/app/MyApp.cfg` file from
  templates using the `jpackage` generated ones as a reference
- Fill in `Contents/app`, `Contents/Resources` with my jar files and other resources

**Creating a pkg on linux:**

https://gist.github.com/msabramo/2a8e44eb6dcc3b89437d33649b0b1841

**Creating a dmg on linux:**

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117461/how-do-i-create-a-dmg-file-on-linux-ubuntu-for-macos

Alternately, migrate from `nsis` to `install4j`

https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html

In theory once I get it all working on linux, I can port the effort to both Darwin and cygwin (WSL just doesn't work right for me atm, will get that working last)

Proof of concept is here (linux, MacOS, cygwin):

https://github.com/nyetwurk/ecuxplot

It is kind of ridiculous this multiplatform crosscompile tooling doesn't exist anywhere, considering the rise of CI/CD, and that the whole point of java is portability and architecture independence.